# SharePoint Online api

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, ajax, office365apis

I made a rest call to list site my users have access :

```
url: '/services/_api/web/webs/?$select=title,ServerRelativeUrl,effectivebasepermissions&$filter=effectivebasepermissions/high%20gt%2032',
```

I made a test user to check if the call works for non admin users and I get odd results.

When I throw this request on a user that should have 0 access to any sites, I get 2 sites with this result :

```
:{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.BasePermissions"},"High":"48","Low":"134287360"}
```

When I got to those two sites, I get an access denied.

When I check the effective permission with the users and group tool, it return : Style Ressource Reader, Limited Access.

When I check on other sites for that same user, I dont have Style Ressource Reader, Limited Access.

I tried to check if some componends had disabled inheritence, but it doesnt seem to be the case.

How can I make sure that the users doesnt get listed with that level of permissions. My request should return only a list of sites that the user should have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I had to remove style ressource reader from the site and add it again. I guess the permission provisionning was bugged.